# How to Increase Limit Of Checkbox by Click Event on Disabled Checkboxes

Tags: jquery

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/04q9qyj6/) and let me know how I can change the limit of checkboxes to 3 and then to no limit every time that user clicks on any of ONLY disabled checkboxes?

The process in first step is if the user checks 2 item the other checkboxes will disabled now if user clicks on any of disabled checkboxes the `#opt-limit-3` will shows up and prompt user the options of increasing the limit or leaving the current situation?! If `Yes` then I need to increase the `limit = 3`

How can I trigger an event on disabled checkboxes?
This doesn't work:

```
$('input:checkbox:disabled').click(function(){ alert("hi"); });
```

I also tried

```
$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("readonly", true);
$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").prop("readonly", true);
```

but now all checkboxes are available to be checked!

Heres a demo:

```js
var limit = 2;


$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
  var bol = $("input:checkbox:checked").length >= limit;
  $("input:checkbox").not(":checked").attr("disabled", bol);

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
  <div class="well">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
    <input type="checkbox">
  </div>

  <div class="well hidden" id="opt-limit-3">
    You have reached the Max Items. Would You Like to Icrease to 3 Items
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="limitTo3" type="submit">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">No</button>
  </div>
  <div class="well hidden" id="opt-no-limit">
    You have reached the Max Items. Would You Like to Icrease to no limit Items
    <button class="btn btn-default" id="toNoLimit" type="submit">Yes</button>
    <button class="btn btn-default" type="submit">No</button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Just for god sake let me know why you have voted this question down?!

Comment: my problem is I  cant trigger event on disabled checkboxed like `$('input:checkbox:disabled').click(function(){
  alert("hi");
});`

Comment: the question is about ebanling predefined diabled checkbox
but in my case I am doing this dynamically
there is no 'readonly="readonly"' in my marup

Comment: so I have to add "readonly att to rest of checkboxes?

Comment: Ok I update the code to ` `$("input:checkbox").not(":checked").prop("readonly", true);` but this just makes all checkboxes selectable!

Comment: You're right. Sorry for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/04q9qyj6/2/)

it works good

```
var limit = 2;

    $("#opt-limit-3").hide();

$("input:checkbox").click(function() 
{
    if($(this).attr('isdisabled') == 'isdisabled')
        return false;

    $(".yo").html($("input:checkbox:checked").length + " ------ "+limit);
    if( $("input:checkbox:checked").length >=limit) 
    {    
        $("input:checkbox:not(:checked)").attr("isdisabled","isdisabled").on("mouseup",function()
        {
            $("#opt-limit-3").show();
        });

    }
});

$("#limitTo3").click(function()
{
    $("input:checkbox[isdisabled]").removeAttr("isdisabled").off("mouseup");
    limit+=3;
    $("#opt-limit-3").hide();
});

$("#limitTo3no").click(function()
{
    $("#opt-limit-3").hide();
});
```